# Scanf to assign one variable to two pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I want to assign one input from a user to two different pointers (I want to read it as both a  float and a char).  Anyone have any ideas on how to do this or an easy way to convert from one to the other?

Comment: What did you try? Hint: scan one, convert to the other.

Comment: By "*a char*", do you mean an 8-bit integer (byte), a string, or a single character code (ASCII code or such)?

Answer (score 1):

```
char inputString[MAX_SIZE]; // Your input will be stored here as a string.
float inputFloat;           // Here's where you will have your input as float
float *inputFloatPointer;

inputFloatPointer = &inputFloat; // Do this if you want 2 pointers, as requested

fgets(inputString, MAX_SIZE, stdin); // Read from your input buffer

if ((sscanf(inputString, "%f", inputFloatPointer)) == 1) // Try to parse it as a float
    printf("You read a float.\n");  // If the parsing succeeds, you have your float
else
    printf("This is no float.\n");  // Else the user typed something that's not a float.
```

Comment: This answer is some explanation short of upvote. A short code comment or two wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

well a char has a integer representation, not a float. You will have to ***MODIFY*** the float into a char representation and then cast that into a char.